# Where to store a list whose retrieval is a time consuming process

Tags: jsf-2

I am trying to create an application which will provide IT services for different organizations.

I have a long form for creating a user where I have to search all users within that organization through LDAP. This turns out to be a time consuming process. I can search all users and later put them into a list and use that list in a different situation. But the problem is that at the same time any administrator can modify or delete a user. I have thought of putting the list into an application scoped bean. But I have a different organization as well, which has totally different set of users.

What is the appropriate solution in such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is not something that can be handled by the scope if you are running multiple instances of a JSF application that all access a single database.

This should be handled by a lock on the object in the database, i.e. when you load the editing view for a user, the user object is locked for editing to the others (like a boolean column named *locked*). Saving or canceling editing, releases the lock (or it expires if the user forgets to do any of it).

Comment: Firstly this is not my requirement. Secondly if I go through your solution, how do I change the existing user list object for a same organization at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Application scoped data are visible to *all users* of your application. That is, if you put some list in application scope, and later reference it in view, it will be the same instance for every user. Also, you should beware of severe concurrency issues imposed by such approach.

Most probably, you **scoping problems** will end when you'll put your list of users in session scope, where it most naturally fits. You'll load the list of users of a particular organization when a user with appropriate rights demands it in some view.

From this point you'll face the actual problems that you're worried of, and those are **problems that arise in a multiuser environment concurrently accessing shared resources** (like administrators modifying users in your example). One of the things that you're afraid of, as it can be followed from your question, is the 'last commit wins' strategy, under which edits made in time by another users before the last user committed the edits will be lost, or overwritten, by the last commit.

This type of problems can be solved by introducing some type of 'locking' on the database level. Basically there are two types of locking: optimistic and pessimistic.

What Is proposed in another answer is an example of *pessimistic locking*, under which no one is allowed to access the data unless database lock is released. The seip is as follows: user who is going to update the data places an exclusive lock preventing other users from manipulating data until the lock is released. The idea behind is that the users will update the database resources synchronously and that possibility must be ruled out no matter how frequent those conflicting updates actually happen.

Another option - *optimistic locking* assumes that many users can access and modify data simultaneously, without locking the database resources. This is typically achieved by storing record version in the database. When a conflict occurs, a user can be prompted about that, preventing information loss. The idea behind is that though conflicting updates are possible, they will in fact be rare, and in any case the user will be notified of that conflict.

Note that the setup without locking, or 'last commit wins' strategy is basically the same as optimistic locking, when the final user always chooses to overwrite the data.

As you can see, there are some approaches to choose from. So first learn about them yourself, then maybe your not-so-like-question will vanish. And if not - you'll be able to come back and post a new question on concrete topic with concrete problem so that we won't speculate but will concentrate on helping you.